# Implementing shadow mapping under DirectX 12

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, directx-12

I would like to implement shadow mapping inside my renderer. I decided to start with Directional lights. To do so i need to address the following:

**1) Render shadow map for each light**
To do so I plan to use DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT shadow maps of 1024x1024 resolution.
For this step a shadow map texture will, HLSL side, look like:

```
RWTexture2D<float> shadowMap : register(t0);
```

Is it a good approach?

To render a shadow map I need to:

- Build the view matrix using the light position and target point.
- Build the perspective matrix using the projection fovy, aspect ratio, near and far. Maybe I should use an orthographic projection?

I need to compute theses values so that the whole scene is visible from the light.
To help my meshes have all an AABB. So how to do it??

**2) Sampling shadow maps inside my forward lighting shader.**
I think to use an array of Texture2D textures.
For this step the shadow mapping textures will, HLSL side, look like:

```
Texture2D<float> shadowMaps[MAX_LIGHTS]: register(t0);
```

**So here is the problem. Once I create an array of textures how
to access textures individually? This is needed for step 1).**

While being **IRRELEVANT**, here my code that create textures:

```
void createTextureArray(const std::vector<const void*>& texInitialDatas,
    Texture::ImageFormat textureFormat,
    unsigned long long bytesPerRow,
    unsigned int width,
    unsigned int height,
    unsigned int depth,
    D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION resourceDimension,
    bool allowUav,
    Dx12TextureHandle& dst)
{
    const unsigned int arraySize = (unsigned int)texInitialDatas.size();

    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC textureDesc = {};
    textureDesc.Dimension = resourceDimension;
    textureDesc.Alignment = 0;
    textureDesc.Width = width;
    textureDesc.Height = height;
    textureDesc.DepthOrArraySize = depth ? depth : static_cast<std::uint16_t>(arraySize);
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;

    switch(textureFormat)
    {
    case Texture::ImageFormat::R8:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UNORM;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::R32S:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_SINT;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::R32F:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::RGBA8:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::RGB32F:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::RGBA32F:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    break;

    default:
        throw CreateTextureException("Unsupported image format");
    }

    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    textureDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN;
    textureDesc.Flags = allowUav ? D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_ALLOW_UNORDERED_ACCESS: D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;

    // Create a default heap.
    HRESULT hr = D3D12Device->CreateCommittedResource(
        &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
        D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
        &textureDesc,
        D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST,
        nullptr,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&dst.buffer));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return;
    }

    dst.format = textureDesc.Format;

    std::string bufferDebugString = "Texture default heap size = " + std::to_string(arraySize);
    std::wstring bufferDebugStringW(bufferDebugString.begin(), bufferDebugString.end());
    dst.buffer->SetName(bufferDebugStringW.c_str());

    if (arraySize && texInitialDatas[0] != nullptr)
    {
        UINT64 textureUploadBufferSize;
        D3D12Device->GetCopyableFootprints(&textureDesc, 0, arraySize, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &textureUploadBufferSize);

        // Now we create an upload heap to upload our texture to the GPU
        ID3D12Resource* textureBufferUploadHeap;

        hr = D3D12Device->CreateCommittedResource(
            &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD),
            D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
            &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(textureUploadBufferSize),
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
            nullptr,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&textureBufferUploadHeap));

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            return;
        }

        std::string uploadDebugString = "Texture upload heap size = " + std::to_string(arraySize);
        std::wstring uploadDebugStringW(uploadDebugString.begin(), uploadDebugString.end());

        textureBufferUploadHeap->SetName(uploadDebugStringW.c_str());

        // Initialize subresources
        std::vector<D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA> subResourceData(arraySize);
        for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < arraySize; ++i)
        {
            subResourceData[i].pData = texInitialDatas[i];
            subResourceData[i].RowPitch = bytesPerRow;
            subResourceData[i].SlicePitch = bytesPerRow * height;
        }

        // Now we copy the upload buffer contents to the default heap
                         
UpdateSubresources(m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList, dst.buffer, textureBufferUploadHeap, 0, 0, arraySize, &subResourceData[0]);


    // Add the upload heap to the resources to be freed later.
    m_pendingResources.push_back(textureBufferUploadHeap);
    }

m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(dst.buffer, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON));
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why are you trying to pass textures in through a constant buffer? You should be binding them through a descriptor table set up by your root signature.
Also, are you following an already established and working implementation? I highly recommend Luna's _Intro to Game Programming with DX12_, which dedicates a whole chapter to shadow mapping.

Comment: My mistake. I updated the post as you said a constant buffer is not necessary